# Excel VBA: How to insert rows and add string of text

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro for a simple Excel spreadsheet with only one column. Basically I have a long list (5000 rows or more). It is a list of numbered object IDs such as follows:

```
object_0001
object_0002
object_0003
...
object_5000
```

My goal is to add 5 rows of text and one blank row before each group of 90 objects. So it would look like this:

```
textadded1
textadded2
textadded3
textadded4
textadded5
(blank row here)
object_0001
object_0002
object_0003
object_0004
...
object_0090
textadded1
textadded2
textadded3
textadded4
textadded5
(blank row)
object_0091
object_0092
...
object_0180
textadded1
textadded2
textadded3
textadded4
textadded5
(blank row)
```

The 5 strings of text I want to add are all just a single word and will be the same string added between each block of 90 objects. Right now I have a macro that will insert blank rows and I am manually going through and copy/pasting the 5 cells of text in manually after I run it. This is the macro code I'm using that does that:

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowNdx As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For RowNdx = 95 To LastRow Step 95
    Rows(RowNdx).Insert
    Rows(RowNdx).Insert
    Rows(RowNdx).Insert
    Rows(RowNdx).Insert
    Rows(RowNdx).Insert
Next RowNdx
'make sure the first FOUR lines are blank'
End Sub
```

Please help me modify the code to add in the text strings I want. This is all for a spreadsheet using only column A.

Comment: ignore my previous comment.. you need to add a second For Loop nested inside the For RowNdx loop... I will write out an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RowNdx As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For RowNdx = 1 To LastRow Step 96
        Rows(RowNdx).Insert
        Rows(RowNdx).Insert
        Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = "textAdded5"
        Rows(RowNdx).Insert
        Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = "textAdded4"
        Rows(RowNdx).Insert
        Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = "textAdded3"
        Rows(RowNdx).Insert
        Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = "textAdded2"
        Rows(RowNdx).Insert
        Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = "textAdded1"
    Next RowNdx
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you so much user4897144.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when inserting or deleting rows in a loop you would start at the bottom and work up so that the inserted/deleted rows do not interfere with your iteration count.

```
Sub insert_6_every_90()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, stp As Long

    stp = 90

    With ActiveSheet   'set worksheet properly like With Sheets("Sheet1")!
        lr = Int(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row / stp) * stp + 1
        For rw = lr To 1 Step -stp
            .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(6, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(5, 1).Formula = "=text(row(1:1), ""\t\e\x\t\a\d\d\e\d0"")"
            .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(5, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(5, 1).Value
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how close to the truth the *Textadded0, Textadded1, etc* was. This populates the five cells at once. If individual text was more appropriates, that portion would likely have to be adjusted.